# Is it possible to add several strings and a bitmap to a ByteArrayOutputStream

Tags: java, android

I'm writing several strings to a ByteArrayOutputStream using a DataOutputStream as follows:

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream dataStream = new DataOutputStream(byteStream);
    dataStream.writeUTF(string1);
    etc.
```

However I would also like to add a Bitmap to the ByteArrayOutputStream.
Is it possible to first write the strings using the DataOutputStream and then write the bitmap directly to the ByteArrayOutputStream using write()?

How would it be possible to know the number of bytes to read when unstreaming it after writing it?
Or is it possible to pass the ByteArrayOutputStream to Bitmap.compress() after the string have been written?

Comment: Have you tried doing this? Have you attempted to read the result and process the content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why you trying to do this but well...
After you write string to dataStream, do flush on dataStream and you will be sure, that stream is ready to eat more data. Next you can write bitmap to byteStream. Do not forget to flush and close streams. All operations should be done in try block. After you write String to dataStream you can take current offset by size() method.

Comment: If its a strange way of doing things, then what is an elegant way of bundling together several strings and a bitmap into a byte array (for sending to an RPC Api that accepts a byte array for arbitrary payload)

Comment: It depands what is in other side. If you have defined protocol like You mentioned (few strings and bitmap) its ok. But remember that if in other side is for example C++ app or something diffrent it could have troubles with reading java strings (UTF8 encoding).

Comment: Its Java to Java where I control the code which is doing the packing/sending on one side and receiving/unpacking on the other.